# What are the root of this polynomial which has no real roots

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

One of the exercises in control systems asks to find the roots of this characteristic equation if $K=1$
$$
(1-K)s^2 + 2(1-K)s + (2-K) = 0
$$
Obviously it has no real roots but is it possible to extend this to the complex plane and if so how one can compute it. Notice: in control systems we use complex plane a lot. This is why I'm thinking there is a way to solve it but I don't know how.

Comment: Ummm.... if $K=1$, the first two terms vanish (regardless whether $s$ is complex), and you're left with $1 = 0$.  How does putting $s$ in the complex plane affect anything?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork that is true but I'm thinking at K=1 the roots are undefined but may be using limit a good approach. I'm not sure how to solve it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it looks like you're just thrashing here.  I see nothing along what you seek.  (Over and out.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation can also be written

$$ (1 - K)(s^2 + 2s + 1) + 1 = 0, $$

which is equivalent to

$$ 1 = (K - 1)(s+1)^2.$$

As $K$ goes to $1,$ then $K - 1$ goes to $0$ and $\lvert s\rvert$ goes to infinity.
The direction from which $K - 1$ approaches $1$ determines which directions $s$ can go; for any value of $K$ other than $1$ there are two choices of $s$.

Comment: so the roots are $-1\pm j\infty$?

Comment: If $K$ approaches $1$ from below along the real axis then you might say that.

Comment: If I apply the quadratic formula, I end up with 
$$
-1 \pm \sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{0}}
$$
Is $\sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{0}} = j\infty$? if so, is this another way to solve this problem beside your invaluable answer?

Comment: If $1/0$ is $+\infty$ then yes. On the other hand, $0 = 0(-1) = 0(j) = 0(-j) = 0(1+j)$ and so forth, so I would say if $1/0$ means anything, it could be at an infinite distance in any direction in the complex plane.